# jQuery Mobile reload only a div every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a simple web (with jQuery mobile),

The main page contain a div (will be reloaded every 10 seconds).

```
 <div id="mainpage" data-role="page" >

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" >
            <h1><font face="Comic Sans Ms">Home</font></h1>
        </div>

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b" >
        <div id="content_to_reload">
         //Reload every 10 seconds
//AJAX call to server   
        </div>
    </div>


    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">       
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="page2.html"><img src="1.png" width="50"></a></li>
                <li><a href="page3.html"><img src="2.png" width="50"></a></li>
                <li><a href="page4.php"><img src="3.png" width="50"></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->
```

This is jQuery to reload content `#content_to_reload`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#content_to_reload').delay(10000).load('myserver.php');
          });
      </script>
```

it already worked. But I have other problems:

1. Every time it was reloaded, Footer look like add other footer
2. when I go to page2.html , every 10 seconds it is also reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

1. you should use `jQuery.html()` instead of `load()`:

   ```
   $('#content_to_reload').html(data);
   ```
2. you should check the current page by using JQM `pagecontainer`:

   ```
   $(document).on('pagecontainershow', function(e, ui) {
     switch (ui.toPage.prop('id')) {
       case 'mainpage':
         // start call to server
         break;
       default:
         // for all other cases, stop call to server
     }
   });
   ```
3. instead of `delay`, use a simple timer:

   ```
   var callInterval = 10; // seconds
   var timerId = setInterval(function() {
     callToServer();
   }, callInterval * 1000);
   ```

   ...which you can stop when you switch active page:

   ```
   clearInterval(timerId);
   ```

Putting it all together: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6wtw9k1y/)